# How to send mail to multiple To addresses

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to send mail to multiple persons (To addresses). I couldn't able to send with below code.

Please help on this.

```
echo "Hi Team, 

Please find 'Report' in attachment.

 
Regards,
XXXXX " | mail -s "Report" -r "abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com" -c "efg@gmail.com" -a /home/usr/Files/Report.xlsx abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: What `mail` program are you using? Does the man page suggest a correct syntax for specifying multiple recipients?

Comment: @larsks, I'm using notepad for writing shell script programs. when i tried to run I'm getting 'Invalid , literal ' error.

Comment: Please include the exact error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

we can send mail to multiple To Addresses separating them by ',' at the end. Please find the answer below.

```
echo "Hi Team, 

Please find 'Report' in attachment.

 
Regards,
XXXXX " | mail -s "Report" -r "xxxx@gmail.com" -c "xxxx@gmail.com" -a /home/usr/Files/Report.xlsx xxxx@gmail.com,xxxx@gmail.com,xxxxx@gmail.com
```